# Performing multiple subqueries against multiple tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have some radius data and a users table in MySQL that I want to obtain information from.  At the moment I have the following query but it's quite slow.. the radacct table has 10 million rows of data and I'm using username as the common linking field as follows in my query:

```
SELECT
`billing_plans`.`PlanName`,
`ipinfo`.`value` as `ip`,
`userbillinfo`.`username`,
(SELECT max(`radacct`.`acctstarttime`) FROM `radacct` WHERE `radacct`.`username` = `userbillinfo`.`username`) AS `lastupdate`,
(SELECT max(`radpostauth`.`authdate`) FROM `radpostauth` WHERE `radpostauth`.`username` = `userbillinfo`.`username`) as authdate,
(SELECT if(`radacct`.`acctterminatecause` != 'Acct-Update', if(`radacct`.`acctterminatecause` = '', 'Online', concat('Offline (', `radacct`.`acctterminatecause`, ')')), 'Offline') FROM `radacct` WHERE `radacct`.`username` = `userbillinfo`.`username` AND `radacct`.`radacctid` = (SELECT max(`radacct`.`radacctid`) FROM `radacct` WHERE `radacct`.`username` = `userbillinfo`.`username`)) AS `status`

FROM `billing_plans`

JOIN `radius`.`userbillinfo`
  ON (`userbillinfo`.`planName` = `billing_plans`.`id` AND `userbillinfo`.`username` = `userbillinfo`.`username`)
JOIN `radius`.`radreply` as ipinfo
  ON (`ipinfo`.`username` = `userbillinfo`.`username` AND `ipinfo`.`attribute` = 'Framed-IP-Address')
JOIN `radius`.`radcheck`
ON (`radcheck`.`username` = `userbillinfo`.`username`)
WHERE `userbillinfo`.`username` = 'username@realm'
```

Here is the output from the query:

```
Reseller - 25/05 Unlimited  xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx username@realm  2022-04-11 11:13:54 2022-04-07 23:48:03 Online
```

This query takes 0.06s, is there a more efficient way I can write this at all? With over 300 usernames in our database and growing, this query becomes very slow over multiple usernames.

Cheers, Mike

Comment: have you tried subqueries or CTEs to gather the wanted information and joined them. but stiill for such question we need to know the design and indexes of all tables. an execution plan and EXPLAIN and ANALSE of the query

Comment: I think you hit the nail on the head - I just ran this query seperately:
`SELECT max(`radacct`.`radacctid`) FROM `radacct` WHERE `radacct`.`username` = 'username@realm'`
It took 0.26s to scan through 10 million rows.  Explain SQL on this table returns 20518 rows.  There is an index created for username as well.

Comment: Such information belongs with all the information in the question not in a comment

Comment: Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`; it may provide some more clues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of these indexes may help:

```
userbillinfo:  INDEX(username, planName)
radcheck:      INDEX(username)
radpostauth:   INDEX(username,  authdate)
radacct:  INDEX(username,  acctstarttime)
radacct:  INDEX(username, radacctid,  acctterminatecause)
ipinfo:   INDEX(username,  value, attribute)
```

When adding a composite index, DROP index(es) with the same leading columns.
That is, when you have both INDEX(a) and INDEX(a,b), toss the former.